# Failure to start grub with Wubi

Tags: 10.04, wubi

My laptop battery ran down and died while using Ubuntu 10.04 with Wubi. Upon recharge (and restart) selecting Ubuntu from the Windows Boot menu brings me to the typical prompt which says (and I paraphrase):

> Trying hd(0,0) on Disk...

After that the screen flickers to white (for a split second) then black. No grub menu comes up (as I would expect) no cursor, no grub sh prompt. Nothing. I've tried switching TTYs to no avail.

As there are no logs, I can't trouble shoot anything. I've run a check disk from windows (on the NTFS partition the root.disk is stored) with no luck. What is causing this failure to load grub (and, by association Ubuntu) - How can I restore my setup and get Ubuntu via Wubi working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this **[thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1639198)**,your solution lies at **Problem #2:**  **Solution #1**

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

your computer was set to automatically update huh?

after intentionally updating our laptop kernal from wubi, (to resolve an unrelated browser/connection issue)
upon restart ubuntu completely hangs at or about the grub start.

after hours of searching how to access my info, i found

this is a known bug..

there currently is no solution.

use a ubuntu live cd, mount the drive, and copy the info from wubi to a thumbdrive, and wait with the rest of us while whatever is hanging everyones system is fixed. ext2 may let you read your image file, no such luck in my case.

(I am fairly tech savy, but not a programmer, after the hanging, I re-wrote the grub, and get a little farther in my boot, but from what i can tell, its the grub2 update not compatible with wubi, where wubi requires grub1 )

wishing you the best

Comment: What known bug? You are referring to an old problem with Grub and Wubi that has been fixed since 11.04 was released. Wubi uses Grub2 and has since release 9.10. This answer does not seem related to the original question.